# Remix / MUI 3rd party components

Tags: remix, remix.run

I am using Remix with Mui pagination component, which exposes a bunch of callbacks for interacting with the component as shown below.

```js
<TablePagination
  component="div"
  count={total}
  page={page}
  onPageChange={handleChangePage}
  rowsPerPage={take}
  onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
/>
```

The challenge here is submiting the Remix Form, what is the recommended way.

This is what I am currently doing, but it forces all the loaders to be called, including the one in the layout file.

```js
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams({
  skip: "0",
  take: "25",
});
const submit = useSubmit();
const { users, total } = useTypedLoaderData<typeof loader>();
const handleChangePage = () => {
  searchParams.set("take", `${take}`);
  setSearchParams(searchParams);
}
```

What is the recommended practice, so multiple calls are not made

Comment: Since Remix doesn't know which routes use the search params, it will call *all* loaders. You can prevent the layout loader to be called via `shouldRevalidate`. https://remix.run/docs/en/1.19.3/route/should-revalidate#ignoring-search-params